# UWP GetThumbnailAsync gives different result depending on files selection system

Tags: c#, image, uwp

I'm experiencing an issue in using GetThumbnailAsync() method of a StorageFile. When file is selected with the file picker the thumbnail is correctly generated; when searching files by using GetFilesAsync(), generic image icon is retrieved.

Code for retrieving files is the following:
`

```
var queryOptions = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.OrderByDate, fileTypeFilter);
queryOptions.FolderDepth = FolderDepth.Deep;

var cacheFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
var result = cacheFolder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);
var files = await result.GetFilesAsync();
```

`

Thumbnail is generated by using:

`var thumbnail = await imageFile.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.SingleItem, (uint)requestedSize, ThumbnailOptions.UseCurrentScale);`

I really don't understand why this difference in result.

NB Of course, I selected PictureLibrary in app manifest file.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The return of these two API is different.

[GetFilesAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder.getfilesasync?view=winrt-22621#windows-storage-storagefolder-getfilesasync) returns `IAsyncOperation<IReadOnlyList<StorageFile>>.`

[PickSingleFileAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker.picksinglefileasync?view=winrt-22621#windows-storage-pickers-fileopenpicker-picksinglefileasync) returns `IAsyncOperation<StorageFile>.`

If you use `files` as `imageFile`. `GetThumbnailAsync` won't work.

> `IReadOnlyList<StorageFile>` does not contain a definition for
> `GetThumbnailAsync` and no accessible extension method
> `GetThumbnailAsync`.

So it is recommended that you use [FileOpenPicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker?view=winrt-22621#methods).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. When I retrieve a list of files I use a foreach loop for generating a thumbnail for each item.

Comment: @Francesco, could you please share the result image you got for both of these ways by updating your question? I tired your code and managed to run it in a blank app. Both of these two ways could get the thumbnail correctly. If you could reproduce this behavior in a blank project, would you mind to share the code with us so we could try to reproduce this behavior?

Comment: hi, I created a simple demo app at the following link: [TestImagesApp](https://github.com/FrancescoCarraro/TestImagesApp.git) By using the Load button I'm able to open any image, By using the Find button, which load all images and try to show them, a lot of images are not shown. I'm missing something....but I'm not able to guess what...

Comment: I'm now a little bit confused about your real question. So the real question is that some of the image is not showing when you are enumerating the file?
To test your sample, I've added many different images(110 files) to the library and I could see all of them are showing in the image after click the find button. Could you please share a screenshot about the behavior to help us understand the scenario better?

Comment: your answer is really interesting to me....I never tried the test app on a different PC, maybe the app works but my windows 11 installation in not giving me right thumbnails. It is returning me the default picture icon for most of fpund pictures.

Comment: Hi @Francesco, I still can't reproduce your problem on my computer(Win11 22621.675 22H2) using the project you shared, could you please provide your computer system version information?

Comment: Hi, my system info are: Win 11 22H2, 22621.900. I'm still investigating the issue....a relevant point could be the following: images are in OneDrive folder. Could it be?

Comment: Hi, after several tests, I found the code now works by using the following line: queryOptions.SetThumbnailPrefetch(Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailMode.SingleItem, 250, Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailOptions.UseCurrentScale);